# Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Tags: php, mysql

I've looked over several SO posts, as well as articles on other websites, and have yet to find a valid answer :(.

**Here's my code:**

```
include("db_conn.php");
$conn = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die(mysql_error()); mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());

$timestamp = time();
$add_time = time()+(60*60);

$query = "SELECT * FROM links WHERE timestamp >= '$timestamp' AND overflow = 'NO'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $link = $row['link'];
        $hit_update = rand($row['min'],$row['max']);

        $query = "UPDATE links SET timestamp = '$add_time', hit_counter = '0', max_hits = '$hit_update' WHERE link = '$link' AND timestamp <= '$timestamp' AND overflow = 'NO'";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
}

mysql_close($conn);
```

**It returns the error:**

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource
```

**To diagnose I've tried:**

- Removing the encasing `if()` statement.
- Commenting out the `while()` loop, and adding `$size = mysql_num_rows($result); echo $size;` below `$result = mysql_query($query);` which returns `3`, i.e. there's nothing wrong with the query itself.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Any answers would be very much appreciated!!

Comment: the problem is in the update
you are overriding $result variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting the `$result` variable that controls the loop within the loop. That's not good. The database resource contains a cursor that you must consume fully or otherwise [dispose of](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-free-result.php), just overwriting it with a new result may not get you the expected results (or indeed get you a runtime error).

Just use a different variable for the query inside the loop.

Comment: You're right, I didn't think about that! I'll accept your answer when the timer drops.